# nested directories and classes in a python library

Tags: python

## Efficient Imports

I have several nested directories in this library I'm building, some nested directories have no files but other directories, or each directory has one or more class files.

The library is basically getting ported from another language, and I have to keep the structure same.

I'm looking for code organization and module access without repetition in the import statements

```
mylib
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│      └── baz.py (class Baz) 
├
test
    ── foo
       ├── bar
           ── test_baz.py
```

The problem I have is with the repetition in my import statement

`from mylib.foo.bar.baz import Baz`

is there a way I can avoid `.baz` in the import statement?

### Attempt (without any real success)

within the `__init__` file, I tried without any real effect.

```
import baz.baz import Baz

__all__ = [
  "Baz"
]
```

Comment: I get `ModuleNotFoundError` in my test class

Comment: No; `baz.py` defines a *module* that contains a class named `Baz`. That class is not defined elsewhere. You aren't repeating anything, beyond the class and the module having similar names.

Comment: If `Baz` were defined in `bar/__init__.py`, then you would use `from mylib.foo.bar import Baz`, because now `Baz` is defined in the module `bar`.

Comment: what I think python does in the `import` statement, it uses the `directoryname. filename.classname`, and since I have same word for the directory and file name, they are repeated in the import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `from .baz import Baz` in `mylib/foo/bar/__init__.py`.

Comment: I tried but nothing is changed in the import statement

Comment: @AppDeveloper Is there an error?

Comment: can you please provide the import statement for the user of this against the solution so I can try the exact.

Comment: @AppDeveloper What do you mean? `from mylib.foo.bar import Baz` should work with this change.

Comment: yes this import statement, and the error is `Cannot find reference 'Baz' in 'imported module mylib.foo.bar' `, I like this approach if we can make it work. If I do `mylib.foo.bar.bar`, then import works fine.

Comment: `from .baz.baz import Baz` this worked! Sweet.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Do you have another directory called baz? @AppDeveloper

Comment: sorry, forget that please. This is the solution to use `__init__` file to work in your favor, what do you call this, and where can I learn more about it? I have been told to keep the init file empty

Comment: is `__init__` some kind of export mechanism to facilitate with nested directories.

Comment: @AppDeveloper You can take a look at this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: And https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html for more depth on imports in general.

Comment: Hi, I have another problem related to this. I noticed on public repos that `mylib` lives inside a `src` folder, so if I move `mylib` into the `src` folder, how do I keep the imports intact, for instance keep using `mylib.foo.bar` instead of `src.mylib.foo.bar`